# How to plot SVM decision boundary using ScikitLearn.jl and Gadfly.jl?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

I want to plot the decision boundary of a SVM model using Gadfly. I have tried `LIBSVM.jl`, but it does not give any coefficients of SVM model. `ScikitLearn.jl` provides `decision_function`, which seems helpful.

I found [this example](https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl/blob/master/examples/Classifier_Comparison.ipynb) using `decision_function` and `PyPlot` to plot the decision boundary. I am wondering how to do that using Gadfly?

In the example, they use `contourf` from `PyPlot`.

```
x_min, x_max = minimum(X[:, 1]) - .5, maximum(X[:, 1]) + .5
y_min, y_max = minimum(X[:, 2]) - .5, maximum(X[:, 2]) + .5
xx, yy = meshgrid(x_min:h:x_max, y_min:h:y_max)

z = reshape(z, size(xx)...)
ax[:contourf](xx, yy, z, cmap=cm, alpha=.8)
```

I tried to use `Geom.contour` in `Gadfly`:

```
plot(z=z, x=xx, y=yy, Geom.contour)
```

It raised error "Stat.contour requires dimension of z to be length(x) by length(y)".

In my example, `z`, `xx`, `yy` are all 200×247 Arrays and they work in `contourf`. I am not sure how to convert `xx`, `yy` into 200×1, and 247×1 arrays, in order to use `Geom.contour`.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `plot(z=z, x=xx[:,1], y=yy[1,:], Geom.contour)`?